# React.js при смене route скрипт продолжает работать

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: дерево]

у меня есть два роута 'Profile' и 'Dialogs'

в 'Profile' есть js скрипт с интервалом , если нажать на Profile то скрипт работает все ок, но если после  нажать на Dialogs то скрипт продолжает работать и по сколку классы не находит выдает ошибку

как остановить скрипт при смене route ?

Comment: линканите весь компонент `Profile`